# Keras training error in shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Writing my first image classifier in Keras, here's the code

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint


# dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 150, 150

train_data_dir = 'training_images'
validation_data_dir = 'validation_images'
nb_train_samples = 2000
nb_validation_samples = 800
epochs = 50
batch_size = 16

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(5))
model.add(Dense(14951, activation='softmax'))

monitor = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=1e-3, patience=5, verbose=0, mode='auto')
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath="best_weights.hdf5", verbose=0, save_best_only=True) # save best model

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', callbacks=[monitor,checkpointer], epochs=1000, metrics=['accuracy'])

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for training
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
# only rescaling
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

model.load_weights('best_weights.hdf5') # load weights from best model
model.save('last_model.h5')
```

when I try to train the model though I get a shape error

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Found 981214 images belonging to 14951 classes.
Found 237925 images belonging to 14951 classes.
Epoch 1/50
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 78, in <module>
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)
  File "/home/muiruri_samuel/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wra
pper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/muiruri_samuel/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 1276, in fit_generato
r
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/home/muiruri_samuel/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wra
pper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/muiruri_samuel/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2224, in fit
_generator
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "/home/muiruri_samuel/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1877, in tra
in_on_batch
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "/home/muiruri_samuel/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1480, in _st
andardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')
  File "/home/muiruri_samuel/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 123, in _sta
ndardize_input_data
    str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have shape (14951,) but got array with shape (1,
)
```

This is the first time I've ever got a shape error.
I've looked for where I might have made a mistake but since this model was based on a binary "santa" or "not santa" I likely suspect I should have given it the shape of the categories to give out in the end.

Comment: Your last layer needs to have the same number of units as the number of categories in your training data (1 in case of binary).

Comment: it's still throwing a similar error, I added an activation layer with the shape of the classes but it's somehow getting a shape of 1 from somewhere.

Comment: I don't understand why you have used `14951` neurons in the last layer. Your last layer should be something like: `Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')`. Because you are doing binary classification and the activation should be sigmoid because you want to map to probability values from real values.

Comment: because there's `14951` classes of images divided into folders. Won't the sigmoid expect only 1-2 classes only?

Comment: I am confused about your dataset now. So, you are trying to classify your images into 14951 different classes ? Yes, sigmoid will assume 2 classes but since you will have a neuron for each of your class, it will work fine with as many classes as you have. Also, if you have multiple classes you will need to use one hot encoding to convert it to a vector. Check for `to_categorical` method in keras.

Comment: I'm not even passing anything to the model except the folder in `ImageDataGenerator` the folders are numbers only and it takes images in a sub folder of say `1920` as images of class `1920` the error where it drops the error from is even hard to figure out.

Comment: Please describe your dataset, how many classes do you have and what is the exact task you are training for?

Comment: it's a google landmark classification and what I've done is for all the images in the training.csv i downloaded it into `training_images` where each images classification e.g. `20023` means it's in a folder `training_images\20023` I also randomly took 20% from each of this folders and populated `validation_images` with the same sub folder as training creating the classes of folders mentioned. This is an object recognition test and the images in a folder have a landmark of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the principal problem is here:

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')
```

As you have 14951 classes, that is not binary classification at all and you set class mode to "binary". This should be set to "categorical":

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')
```

Then the labels produced by the generators will have the correct shapes and training should work.